# Code to print the Longest Common Substring in C

Tags: c

I wrote the code to print the longest common substring in C language perogramming. When I run the code it says "segmentation core dumped". Please help me I want to know the problem because it was working at first and then it suddenly gave this error.

```
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define new_max(x,y) (((x) >= (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define new_min(x,y) (((x) <= (y)) ? (x) : (y))

void LCSubStr(char *X, char *Y, int m, int n)
{
    int LCSuff[m+1][n+1];
    int result = 0;
    int end;

    for (int i=0; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                LCSuff[i][j] = 0;

            else if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1])
            {
                LCSuff[i][j] = LCSuff[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                result = new_max(result, LCSuff[i][j]);
                end = i - 1;
            }
            else{
         LCSuff[i][j] = 0;
        }
        }
    }

    if(result = 0){
        printf("No common substring");
    }else{
        char subbuff[5];
        memcpy(subbuff, &X[end - result + 1], result);
        subbuff[result] = '\0';
        printf("%s",subbuff);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char X[] = "Sandile";
    char Y[] = "andile";

    int m = strlen(X);
    int n = strlen(Y);

    LCSubStr(X, Y, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying to a fixed length string, you can directly specify the length with printf.

```
        char subbuff[5];
        memcpy(subbuff, &X[end - result + 1], result);
        subbuff[result] = '\0';
        printf("%s",subbuff);
```

Instead, try:

```
printf("%.*s",result, &X[end-result+1])
```

(The '.*s' syntax uses a limit in the parameter list - the `result` or length of match in this case)

Also, be careful of `=`.

```
    if(result = 0){
        printf("No common substring");
```

It's traditional to reverse comparisons in C to avoid this typo.

```
   if (0 == result) { 
       printf("No common substring");
```

Comment: It is still saying "segmentation core dumped" when I tr:

**printf("%.*s",result, &X[end-result+1]);**

Answer (score 0):

I believe, in this statement

```
if(result = 0){
```

`=` is typo and you mean `==` i.e. `if (result == 0) ...`.

Your program is accessing an array beyond its size, which is an undefined behaviour:

```
        char subbuff[5];
        memcpy(subbuff, &X[end - result + 1], result);
```

the size of `subbuff` is `5` and the size of longest common substring, for the given input (`X = "Sandile"` and `Y = "andile"`), is `6`. The `memcpy`, while copying the bytes, end up accessing the array `subbuff` beyond its size. You need a destination buffer of minimum size `7` (`6` characters + `1` null terminating character) to hold the common substring (for the given input).

As @Halt State suggested, you can print the specific number of characters of input string, starting from a position in the string:

```
    if(result = 0){
        printf("No common substring");
    }else{
        printf("%.*s",result, &X[end-result+1]);
    }
```

Alternatively, you can allocate the memory dynamically and copy the longest common string in that memory. In this case, instead of printing longest common string in `LCSubStr()` function, you may return it from `LCSubStr()` function which enables the calling function to process something based on the returned string, if required. It's implementation:

```
....
#include <stdlib.h>    // for malloc
....

char * LCSubStr (char *X, char *Y, int m, int n) {
    ....
    ....
    char * subbuff = NULL;
    if (result > 0) {
        subbuff = malloc (result + 1);
        if (subbuff == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memcpy (subbuff, &X[end - result + 1], result);
        subbuff[result] = '\0';
    }
    return subbuff;
}

// In the calling function
int main (void) {
    ....
    ....
    char * lcs = LCSubStr (X, Y, m, n);
    if (lcs != NULL) {
        printf ("%s\n", lcs);
        // Once the calling function done with returned buffer, free it
        free (lcs);
    } else {
        printf ("No common substring\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```